# How to load external in Pure Data 0.46-7 (Mac) correctly?

Tags: puredata

I'm having some trouble trying to load zexy and iemlib into Pd Vanilla 0.46-7. I had no problems compiling and installing cyclone from https://github.com/electrickery/pd-cyclone. It works fine. So I tried installing iemlib and zexy from https://github.com/iem-projects/pd-iem using their binaries but there's something wrong going on. When I turn on "verbose" under path preferences, PD seems to be looking for a file with the same name as the object I'm trying to use. Using [zexy/multiplex] in a patch gives:

```
tried ~/Library/Pd/zexy/multiplex.d_fat and failed
tried ~/Library/Pd/zexy/multiplex.pd_darwin and failed
tried ~/Library/Pd/zexy/multiplex/multiplex.d_fat and failed
```

But there's no multiplex.d_fat only zexy.d_fat. Same with iemlib, there's no dollarg.d_fat or dollarg.pd_darwin only iem_mp3.d_fat, iem_t3_lib.d_fat, iemlib1.d_fat, and iemlib2.d_fat. I'm guessing these files are where the externals were compiled in.

I tried using deken and iemlib installs the .pd_darwin files but I guess this is an older version(?) and zexy is still installing zexy.d_fat so I can't load its objects.

I also tried loading the lib "zexy/zexy" under startup preferences and it loads ok but then I get messages like:

```
warning: class 'abs~' overwritten; old one renamed 'abs~_aliased'
```

and I seem to loose namespace functionality, I can no longer refer to [zexy/multiplex] and need to use only [multiplex], which I guess is the correct behaviour.

How does Pd know how to look for objects on files with different names?

Any advice?

This thread is marked as solved http://forum.pdpatchrepo.info/topic/9677/having-trouble-with-deken-plugin-and-zexy-library-solved and sounds like a similar problem but I haven't been successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zexy` is built as a multi-object library, so there is no separate binary for `zexy/multiplex`.
As you have correctly guessed, the correct way to load zexy is a whole (either using `[declare -lib zexy]` in your patch or adding `zexy` to the startup libs (no need to use `zexy/zexy`)), and ignore the warning about *abs~*.

as for how loading works:

- Pd maintains a list of objects it knows how to create. e.g. whenever you create `[pack]`, Pd will lookup *pack* in its list of known-objects and use the information found there to actually create the object.
- If you try to create an object that Pd doesn't know about yet (e.g. `[foo]`), then Pd will look for a library named *foo* (e.g: `foo.pd_linux`) and if found, it will "load" it.
- *loading* a library means that it will call a special function in the library (this special function is the entry point of the library and is called `foo_setup()` in our case)
- after that, Pd will check, whether it *now* has `foo` in the list of known objects. if it does, it will create the object.

Now the magic is done in the special function, that is called when Pd *loads* the library: this function's main purpose is to tell Pd about new objects (basically saying: "if somebody asks for object "foo", i can make one or you").
When zexy's special function is loaded, it tells Pd about *all* zexy objects (including `multiplex`), so after Pd has loaded zexy, it knows how to create the `[multiplex]` object.

If the special function registers an object that Pd *already* knows about (e.g. in the case of zexy it tries to register a new object `abs~` even though Pd already has a built-in object of the same name), then Pd will rename the original  object by appending `_aliased` and the newly registered object will take over the name.

Comment: Thanks, it's more or less what I figured. So, If I add two libraries that include objects with conflicting names (say iemlib/wrap and zexy/wrap) will it register the first one and "alias" the other one? Is this special function a C function? I was hoping to use namespaces to avoid this type of problem.

Comment: For those who've arrived here later, say around 2021, I could only successfully load zexy by using `zexy/zexy` contrary even to the official instructions here: https://git.iem.at/pd/zexy

System: pd 0.51.3 / OS X 11.2.3 / zexy 2.3.1